# ng-animate in ng-if is not working when changing ng-if condition asynchronously (in callback function)

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I can make ng-animate working in ng-if when I change the ng-if condition in normal function, like

My view:

```
 <div ng-if="!show">
   <a ng-click="showWorld()">Hello</a> 
 </div>
 <div ng-if="show" class="animation">
   Hello world!
 </div>
```

My function in the directive:

```
 scope.showWorld = function() {
     scope.show = true;
 }
```

Above will work when I call the showWorld() function to change ng-if condition, the Hello world! will show up with animation, but if I do:

```
 scope.showWorld = function() {
     Post.test(params, function(){
        scope.show = true;   
     })
 }
```

Post is the angular $resource something like: 
`$resource('api/post', {}, {test: {method: 'POST'}})`

And scope.show will still be changed and Hello world! still show up but the animation is not working...

I've searched online for a long time but can't find the answer, can someone tell me why??

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you need a $scope.$apply() call around your action function, eg:

```
scope.showWorld = function() {
     Post.test(params, function(){
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.show = true;   
        });  
     })
 }
```

You can also use `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){})` as an alternative

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried this way before but got 
"Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress $digest already in progress" 
error message.

Comment: See my comment about using $evalAsync - it may help.

Comment: Hi I tries $evalAsync and still not working... the weird thing is it seems working in Safari but not in chrome......